# Reporting tool for flutter_driver

Tags: report, flutter-test, flutterdriver

I was searching for a reporting tool for flutter integration tests (flutter_driver) that will generate an HTML document.

But I couldn't find any.

I have tried Ozzie. But on Windows Ozzie don't work - There is an issue. The library seems to be dead because lib wasn't updated for a long time.

Also, I tried lib called screenshot. Also, there was an issue and this lib is also death.

I wrote my own solution for making a screenshot using the flutter_driver screenshot method. But it will be nice to have also a tool for generating an HTML report.